# How to turn a file name into a date time code? (11-25-21 1530 to 11/25/21 15:30)

Tags: excel, vba

I use a macro to load an Excel file, pull data, and paste it into a log file. Each of the source Excel files are named by the sample date time it was created.

For instance, a sample created November 25th, 2021 at 3:30 PM would have the file name "11-25-21 1530". I want to pull the file name, assign it to a variable, and format that string into the date time format recognized by Excel for plotting (11/25/21 15:30). I cannot change the file names to include the "/" or ":" since these are not valid in file names.

I have something similar using a userform for time only where it autoformats into a 24hr time variable:

```vb
Private Sub TextBox2_AfterUpdate()

   'Input would be HHMM or HMM

    Dim a As String
    a = Len(Me.TextBox2)
    If a <= 2 Then 'This is for cases with H or HH
        On Error Resume Next
        Me.TextBox2 = Left(Me.TextBox2, a) & ":" & 0 
    ElseIf a = 3 Then
        Me.TextBox2 = Left(Me.TextBox2, 1) & ":" & Right(Me.TextBox2, 2) 'This is for cases with HMM
    Else
        If Me.TextBox2.Value >= 2400 Then
            MsgBox ("Incorrect Value")
            Call CommandButton1_Click
        Else
            Me.TextBox2 = Left(Me.TextBox2, 2) & ":" & Right(Me.TextBox2, 2) 'This is for cases with HHMM
        End If
    
    End If
    Me.TextBox2 = Format(Me.TextBox2, "HH:MM")
End Sub
```

How do I take the file name and split it into a date and then a time, format both to the proper Excel date time format, then combine them again for MM/DD/YY HH:MM output to log the results?

Answer (score 1):

Use simple string handling to split the name into it's pieces. Then use `DateSerial` and `TimeSerial` to create a real `Date` out if it.

Once that is done, you can do whatever you want with the `Date`. I don't understand your request "*into the date time format recognized by excel for plotting (11/25/21 15:30)*", I **do** know that **my** Excel will have a hard time to understand `11/25/21` correctly (I am not located in the US...). When you write the date into a cell, write it as date and format the cell. If you need it in your code as string, use the `Format`-command.

The following function will split a filename, just note that there is no error handling or plausability test.

```
Function FilenameToDate(filename As String) As Date
    Dim fileYear As Long, fileMonth As Long, fileDay As Long, fileHour As Long, fileMinute As Long
    
    fileDay = Val(Mid(filename, 4, 2))
    fileMonth = Val(Mid(filename, 1, 2))
    fileYear = Val(Mid(filename, 7, 2))
    fileHour = Val(Mid(filename, 10, 2))
    fileMinute = Val(Mid(filename, 13, 2))
    
    FilenameToDate = DateSerial(fileYear, fileMonth, fileDay) + TimeSerial(fileHour, fileMinute, 0)
    
End Function
```